# convert bash script to python without subprocess

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, subprocess

How do I convert following into python without using subprocess command

```
cat  $MYDIR/*  |grep ABCD |grep zip |grep -v idx |awk -F'/' '{print $3}'  |awk -F"_" '{print $2}'  |awk -F"." '{print $1}'  |sed 's/\$[A-Z]//g' |   sort|uniq  |egrep -v "^ABCD_G9" |egrep -v ABCD_00 |egrep -v "^ABCD_0[1-8]"  > $DATADIR/ABCDDataFile
```

Comment: could you provide an example along with expected output?

Comment: You seem to be expecting us to write something that does all this for you. What specifically about python doing any of this do you have a question about?

Comment: Input
data/201412/ABCD_13-72.MDAT.zip
data/201412/ABCD_13-73$A.DAT.zip
data/201412/ABCD_13-73$B.DAT.zip 

Output  
13-72
13-73

Comment: @user3376169 your first job is to try something, then you will have specific questions. We will then answer those questions.

Comment: @user3376169 the comment is totally unreadable -- **edit your Q** to show the example input and out properly formatted as lines  (in a block indented by 4 spaces with empty lines around it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You "decompose" the pipeline, understand what each piece does, then re-code each piece in Python, connecting as appropriate.  So, let's see...:

```
cat  $MYDIR/*  |
```

This part concatenates all files residing in the directory whose name is in environment variable `MYDIR`.  So that might be implemented e.g as (after the proper imports of course)

```
def p1():
    filenames = glob.glob(os.environ['MYDIR'] +'/*')
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                yield line
```

using a generator to simulate the buffered simultaneity of shell's pipes.

```
grep ABCD |
```

This part accepts lines and only emits those that contain 'ABCD'.  So for example

```
def grep(pattern, inseq):
    for line in inseq:
        if pattern in line: yield line
```

and similarly for

```
grep zip |
```

next part,

```
grep -v idx |
```

just requires the inverting of `grep`, so:

```
def grepv(pattern, inseq):
    for line in inseq:
        if pattern not in line: yield line
```

and so forth.  Translating `egrep` and `sed` requires regular expressions but is otherwise very similar so I'll leave those bits to you; `awk` as used here just requires a `.split` by the various "field separators" and the indexing of the resulting list.

```
sort | uniq |
```

is actually best translated into a single piece:

```
def sortuniq(inseq):
    for line in sorted(set(inseq)): yield line
```

(Using a generator for uniformity with the previous cases).

So, once you've translated each piece, you just connect them in whatever way you prefer.

The simple way to connect is via function call, but that requires a somewhat innatural order whereby the leftmost piece (the "source", `p1`) becomes the innermost argument to deeply nested calls.  By doing `import this` at an interactive interpreter prompt, we learn among other koans of wisdom that "flat is better than nested".

A little fancy (using `functools.partial` to pre-bind leading args where needed, thus leaving only filter functions that take just `inseq` as their argument) can go a long way...:

```
def pipeline(source, *filters):
    curf = source
    for f in reversed(filters):
        curf = functools.partial(f, curf())
    for line in curf():
        yield line
```

And to write the result to some file,

```
with open(whatever, 'v') as f:
    f.writelines(
        pipeline(
            p1, 
            functools.partial(grep, 'ABCD'),
            functools.partial(grep, 'zip'),
    # etc, etc
```

Would I actually code this way?  Most likely not -- I'd reverse engineer what the whole pipeline is trying to do, rather than go at it piece by piece and connect them all in the end.  While Python is a flexible, multi-paradigm language, using it to strictly emulate the pipeline approach typical of a shell is **not** operationally optimal.  However, it can be quite instructive, which is why I went to some length to show it here!

Comment: I'm not really sure this counts as answer.

Comment: I was about to say the same. Technically, it does answer the question, which is "how to do it", but the real issue is with the quality of the question itself.

Comment: Can you pls. tell me how to decompose the pipeline

Comment: @user3376169, I've gone a long way towards that - now, try finishing the few missing bits as I've amply explained, edit your Q to show your attempt, tell us what (if anything) is going wrong with it (in as small a compass as feasible) -- IOW, **ask a proper Stack Overflow question**, and we'll answer it (unless it gets deleted first, as it might be since as it stands now it does have the problems that prompted 3 people to vote to close it).

Comment: @MightyPork, it might not have been detailed enough in the first edit, but I do hope it's way plenty now!

Comment: @Reti43, I agree the Q is badly presented; I thought it more useful to do some "teaching to fish" so the OP can present it much better, rather than vote to close it.  Translating a shell pipeline into a Python script is a common enough problem, and I presented one technique that one could use for the purpose.